# FFMPEG - Non-Monotonous DTS on concat

Tags: ffmpeg

I have several files I need to concat. It seems sometimes the files work and concat without an issue. Then on other files, the files won't concat and I get the "non-monotonous DTS". I've been googling on what should I make equal on those files so that they concat correctly but I still haven't found out.

Is there anyway to make the DTS exactly the same for all the files? Can I reencode the files with FFMPEG and expect al DTS to be monotonous? I believe I tried reencoding them, It took a while, the size increased but I seemed to get the same errors.

Comment: FWIW, [there is similar question at Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/605818/ffmpeg-non-monotonous-dts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of tries without any result I changed to Mp4Box and started working with the same plugins.

MP4Box -cat path/to/video1.mp4 -cat path/to/video2.mp4 -cat path/to/video3.mp4 -new path/to/output.mp4

Answer (score 3):

Same problem, I got it work with reencoding files in libx264 before concat :

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac out.mp4
```

( The problem was persistent with mpeg4 reencoding )