# Non-monotonous DTS in output for audio stream using ffmpeg concat

Tags: ffmpeg

This was asked in [FFMPEG - Non-Monotonous DTS on concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458807/ffmpeg-non-monotonous-dts-on-concat). But the poster simply opted for MP4Box after getting no reply. However, I would like to stick with ffmpeg which I think is quicker.

I am concatenating files from a text file list of mp4 files that have been encoded at the same time using the same codecs so there should be no incompatibility between the files.

I am not even sure what Non-monotonous DTS is (anyone?) but I am worried it may produce some glitches in the concatenated files. They seem ok but there is some evidence of artefacts in the sound.  Can I tweak my command line to get rid of this error, and will it speed up the concatenation process?
I am using Python subprocess call and the file passed into this function is the list of files. The function decorator is just a timer function for profiling.
I have tried this with my system ffmpeg not just the static build, and it has the same problem.

```
@fn_timer
def concat(file):
    proc = call(['/opt/jane_ng/jane_nodejs/ffmpeg-git-20150308-64bit-static/ffmpeg', '-f', 'concat', '-i', file, '-c', 'copy', '-y', 'testConcat.mp4'])
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```css
ffmpeg version N-45007-g9d7e42e-   http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/    Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-shared --disable-debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --enable-libvidstab --cc=gcc-4.9
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 12.100 /  5. 12.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[concat @ 0x31bdd80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, concat, from '/opt/combinatoria/generator/concatFiles/concat.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1625 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1561 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Unknown: none
Output #0, mp4, to 'testConcat.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1561 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 253952, current: 250488; changing to 253953. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 253953, current: 252536; changing to 253954. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 754296, current: 751464; changing to 754297. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 754297, current: 753512; changing to 754298. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 974696, current: 971964; changing to 974697. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 974697, current: 974012; changing to 974698. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 1340604, current: 1337112; changing to 1340605. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 1340605, current: 1339160; changing to 1340606. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 1746712, current: 1742832; changing to 1746713. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 1746713, current: 1744880; changing to 1746714. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2119664, current: 2116800; changing to 2119665. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2119665, current: 2118848; changing to 2119666. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2274496, current: 2272032; changing to 2274497. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2274497, current: 2274080; changing to 2274498. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2685728, current: 2683044; changing to 2685729. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2685729, current: 2685092; changing to 2685730. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2850980, current: 2847096; changing to 2850981. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 2850981, current: 2849144; changing to 2850982. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3033464, current: 3030552; changing to 3033465. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3033465, current: 3032600; changing to 3033466. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3384856, current: 3381588; changing to 3384857. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3384857, current: 3383636; changing to 3384858. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3760468, current: 3757320; changing to 3760469. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3760469, current: 3759368; changing to 3760470. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3990792, current: 3988404; changing to 3990793. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3990793, current: 3990452; changing to 3990794. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 4295604, current: 4291812; changing to 4295605. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 4295605, current: 4293860; changing to 4295606. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 4750564, current: 4746924; changing to 4750565. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 4750565, current: 4748972; changing to 4750566. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 5025452, current: 5022108; changing to 5025453. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 5025453, current: 5024156; changing to 5025454. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 5271964, current: 5269068; changing to 5271965. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 5271965, current: 5271116; changing to 5271966. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 5707340, current: 5704776; changing to 5707341. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 5707341, current: 5706824; changing to 5707342. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 6003784, current: 6001128; changing to 6003785. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 6003785, current: 6003176; changing to 6003786. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 6371816, current: 6368040; changing to 6371817. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 6371817, current: 6370088; changing to 6371818. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 6875944, current: 6872544; changing to 6875945. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 6875945, current: 6874592; changing to 6875946. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7042528, current: 7040124; changing to 7042529. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7042529, current: 7042172; changing to 7042530. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7314556, current: 7311780; changing to 7314557. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7314557, current: 7313828; changing to 7314558. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7541156, current: 7537572; changing to 7541157. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7541157, current: 7539620; changing to 7541158. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7795620, current: 7791588; changing to 7795621. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7795621, current: 7793636; changing to 7795622. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 8063972, current: 8059716; changing to 8063973. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 8063973, current: 8061764; changing to 8063974. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 8063974, current: 8063812; changing to 8063975. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 8350532, current: 8347248; changing to 8350533. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 8350533, current: 8349296; changing to 8350534. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 8656496, current: 8652420; changing to 8656497. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 8656497, current: 8654468; changing to 8656498. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 8902276, current: 8899380; changing to 8902277. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 8902277, current: 8901428; changing to 8902278. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 9159476, current: 9156924; changing to 9159477. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 9159477, current: 9158972; changing to 9159478. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 9468220, current: 9465624; changing to 9468221. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 9468221, current: 9467672; changing to 9468222. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 9748248, current: 9744336; changing to 9748249. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x3255080] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 9748249, current: 9746384; changing to 9748250. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame= 5637 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   45617kB time=00:03:45.60 bitrate=1656.4kbits/s    
video:43701kB audio:1792kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.272048%
Total time running concat: 0.451297044754 seconds
```

This process is absolutely key to my current project so any help or clarification would be really appreciated.

Comment: While this file appears to play fine in VLC once I start streaming it from a server it gets out of audio sync. Still investigating...

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, it worked and streamed without a hitch once I re-encoded the source files that I fed into the ffmpeg concat command. No DTS errors when processing and it streamed with audio in sync from the server.